# How to click center of iframe after 10 seconds

Tags: iframe

Hey guys anyone knows how to click an iframe after 10 seconds?
I can't do it with javascript,, On load click dons't work because iframe doesn't have a link.

Comment: what is your reasoning for doing this? is the iframe on the same server? are you trying to obtain focus?? we need more info..

Comment: im trying to experiment with iframes, yes it is on the same server. and what if its on the other server..

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that iframe is fully loaded before you trigger the click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('iframe').load(function(){
  //put your click trigger here
});
```